# Weblogic JMS Queue - List of consumer threads' source IP addresses

Tags: jms, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

In a Weblogic Server running its own message broker and queues, is there a way of listing/viewing the source IP addresses from which consumer threads consume messages off a given queue?

Comment: There are ways of listing who is connected to your server: https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/weblogic_server_jms_wlst_script Which might help you get started

Comment: Thanks @DisplayNameismissing, I have been trying to get that script running but without much success. See my other post: [Weblogic WLST connect() with blank username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745214/weblogic-wlst-connect-with-blank-username-and-password) though I think I am asking the wrong question there as I am not familiar with any/many things Weblogic...