# Weblogic WLST connect() with blank username and password

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I am trying to connect to a t3 url which I am told has a blank username and password but, I don't know how to pass an empty username and password in the connect() call. How can I do this?

When I do `connect('', '', 't3://hostname:port')`, WLST tries to connect to the given url using username 'weblogic' which I don't know where it is getting from?

--- UPDATE ---

Please ignore the above... See Sandra's comment.

The script I am trying to run is the one shown in [WebLogic Server JMS WLST Script – Who is Connected To My Server](https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/weblogic_server_jms_wlst_script). Although I have lightly modified it to pass username, password and url as arguments into the script...

I have saved the script to a file named: `listJmsQueueConsumers.py` and I run the script as follows:

`$ source /opttest/bea/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh`

`$ java weblogic.WLST listJmsQueueConsumers.py "username" "password" "t3://ip-address:port"` where, the username, password and url are the admin's username, password and url pointing to weblogic server's administrator port.

Now, when I run the script, I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3://ip-address:port: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset; No available router to destination`

I have also tries running the script with the same url but using protocol `t3s` and, when I run the script using `t3s`, I get:

`Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3s://ip-address:port: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090542]Certificate chain received from bc2-06-v1.compass.cnsonline.net - ip-address was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure. Check the certificate chain to determine if it should be trusted or not. If it should be trusted, then update the client trusted CA configuration to trust the CA certificate that signed the peer certificate chain. If you are connecting to a WLS server that is using demo certificates (the default WLS server behavior), and you want this client to trust demo certificates, then specify -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust on the command line for this client.; No available router to destination`

I am pretty sure the ip address and port I use are the server's ip address and administrator port but I am not sure what the errors actually mean. Do I need some sort of SSL certificate to connect via t3s protocol?

Comment: There is no such thing as a blank admin user/pass combination.... There is ALWAYS an admin user

Comment: Hello @SandraW, I think you are right because whenever I leave those blank it forces me to enter a username and password to use. However, I am not too sure what the problem actually is with the script I am trying to run. I am not familiar at all with Weblogic environments, WLST, etc. I'll edit the main question with some further info on the errors I get when I try run the script...

Answer (score 0):

You will need import the certificate from the WebLogic server to the local keystore being used by your local Java client JVM. I use a tool called KeyStore Explorer (http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/) to do this. Other good options are listed here [How to properly import a selfsigned certificate into Java keystore that is available to all Java applications by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail)